# Aligning titles of tcolorboxes

Tags: titles, tcolorbox, alignment

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{roundedbox/.style={
        breakable,  % allows linebreaks
        enhanced,
        outer arc=5pt,
        arc=5pt,
        colframe=Green,
        colback=Green!10,
        boxed title style={
            colback=Green,
            outer arc=0pt,
            arc=0pt,
            top=3pt,
            bottom=3pt,
        },
        fonttitle=\sffamily
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{question_rounded}[2][]{
    roundedbox,
    title=Question~\thetcbcounter: {#1},
    colback = white,
    label=#2
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{question_rounded}[Here comes a possibly long title, which stretches over several lines and of which the next line should be directly east of ``Question 1:'']{label}
        Here comes the answer.
    \end{question_rounded}
\end{document}
```

The output: [image]

How can I align the question such that each new line is east of the "Question xy:" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `\parbox` for the title.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{roundedbox/.style={
        breakable,  % allows linebreaks
        enhanced,
        outer arc=5pt,
        arc=5pt,
        colframe=Green,
        colback=Green!10,
        boxed title style={
            colback=Green,
            outer arc=0pt,
            arc=0pt,
            top=3pt,
            bottom=3pt,
        },
        fonttitle=\sffamily
    }
}

\usepackage{calc} % added <<<<<<<<
\newlength{\questionlabel}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{question_rounded}[2][]{
    roundedbox,
    title=Question~\thetcbcounter:\enspace{\settowidth{\questionlabel}{\widthof{Question~\thetcbcounter:\enspace}}\parbox{\linewidth-\questionlabel}{#1}},
    colback = white,
    label=#2
}

\begin{document}
            
    \begin{question_rounded}[Here comes a possibly long title, which stretches over several lines and of which the next line should be directly east of ``Question 1:'']{label}
        Here comes the answer.
    \end{question_rounded}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I absolutely forgot about the parboxes.

Comment: and my typo in the MWE :/

Comment: @Manuel ManUser I also missed the typo. Thank you for your feedback!